# How to call a class function inside document.addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

When I load a page I am calling `addEventListener` to initialize `deviceReady`, inside that `addEventListener` I want to call a function which is inside a class. See the following example:

Example class

```
var HomePageModel = function(){
    
    this.initModule = function(){
    //doing some process;
    };
};
```

I want to call the above `initModule` function in `addEventListener`.

Like

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", HomePageModel.initModule, false);
```

Is it possible to call class function inside a `eventlistener` which is outside of a class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an instance first:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", new HomePageModel().initModule, false);
```

Note that if your `initModule` method uses `this`, it won't work, because `this` will be set to the element that triggered the event. To avoid that, you can create a new function bound to a fixed value of `this`:

```
var model = new HomePageModel();
var boundFn = model.initModule.bind(model);
document.addEventListener("deviceready", boundFn, false);
```

Finally, you can always use a wrapper function as the event handler, and call your module initializer from there (not sure why you haven't considered that):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    new HomePageModel().initModule();
}, false);
```

Comment: @SLaks Inside the function, yes. But I'm not sure if it's needed.